# SWFUpload - breaks on DOM Manipulation

Tags: jquery, swfupload

Has anyone found a way around this yet? I have a project where the client wants the Flash button to have a progress bar embedded within it. So far i'm doing this by having a Div with CSS hidden and then displayed after the file has started uploading.

The Button is then hidden however when the button is hidden the event's stop firing. This is the same even I only modify the CSS to move it around the screen.

Comment: Does any manipulation of the button result in the events not firing?

Comment: Yes, the only thing I can do is set the visibility to hidden, however I need the progress bar to hold the position of the button (Kind of like the button having a progress bar)

It doesnt really make much sense to me but as I can now set the visibility to hidden, I guess I can use CSS to position the progress bar over where it used to be.

Comment: Have you tried setting the button to size 1x1 and then positioning the progress bar over it?

Comment: I have tried however I found that anything that causes the element to reinitialize will break the flash.

Answer (score 1):

```
.helper-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: -99999px;
}
```

when you are uploading, add the `helper-hidden` class to the button and remove it when you're done. You can even apply this class to any element you wish to 'hide' from the viewport without affecting it's visibility.

Comment: Anything that causes the flash video to reinitialize breaks it sadly, Setting its visibility to hidden works however getting the progress are positioned on-top is a bit of a pain :)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to fix it was to use Visibility:hidden for a SWFUpload div, this lets the flash still run and doesn't break the Flash / Browser connection.

Answer (score 0):

Old question brought back.

This problem still appear SWFUpload 2 by the time I post this.

The problem cause by positioning. Basically the SWFUpload position a flash file on top of a Link that use by SWFUpload. It initialize the position since onLoad function. After manipulate your DOM, probably you have change some of the dom that positioned on upper of SWFUpload.

Test case:

I have a div that split page to 2. Left side contain SWFUpload, Right side does not.
Both side contain a button to add a dom on the position that upper to SWFUpload

```
------------------------------------
   DOM 1           |       DOM 2
   SWF UPLOAD      |     
   Button 1        |       Button 2
-------------------------------------
```

When user click the button1, it will show dom1. Same for the Button 2.

When user start loading the page. SWFUPload works fine. I then click Button1 to show the DOM 1, then SWFUpload does not work anymore.
Again with button 2, SWFUpload still works.

Also base on my case SWFUpload also does not works on table.

I will report this as a bug to SWFUpload